# Entity Framework TryUpdateModel Child Objects?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I know most of you will suggest that I should use ViewModels specific to the form I am using, but I am curious as to why my child object is not binding on TryUpdateModel.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>User</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PrimaryAddress.AddressId)
    <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PrimaryAddress.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PrimaryAddress.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PrimaryAddress.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PrimaryAddress.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PrimaryAddress.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PrimaryAddress.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsApproved)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsApproved)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsApproved)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsEmployee)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsEmployee)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsEmployee)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

And the controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection form)
{
    var user = Token.DB.Users.Include("PrimaryAddress").Single(x => x.UserId == id);
    if (TryUpdateModel(user, new string[] { "UserName", "Email", "IsApproved", "IsEmployee", "PrimaryAddress.FirstName", "PrimaryAddress.LastName" }))
    {
        try
        {
            Token.DB.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("index");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            while (ex.InnerException != null)
                ex = ex.InnerException;
            if (ex.Message.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("unique"))
                ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "UserName already exists");
        }
    }
    return View(User);
}
```

The code doesn't throw any exceptions, it just doesn't populate the user.PrimaryAddress.FirstName or user.PrimaryAddress.LastName from the form. I'd like to know why?

I already know I can fix the issue with a specific ViewModel and mapping the info in the background. I can also do something like this:

```
<!-- Edit.cshtml -->
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PrimaryAddress.FirstName, null, "FirstName")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PrimaryAddress.FirstName)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PrimaryAddress.LastName)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PrimaryAddress.LastName, null, "LastName")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PrimaryAddress.LastName)
</div>

// UsersController.cs
if (TryUpdateModel(user, new string[] { "UserName", "Email", "IsApproved", "IsEmployee"})
&& TryUpdateModel(user.PrimaryAddress, new string[] {"FirstName", "LastName" }))
```

So the real question is why isn't it binding in the first example?

Comment: Not sure why the -1, stated my question clearly and gave examples. Should I just blindly follow the MVC purist motto of view specific models for everything without understanding what is going on underneath the hood? Thank you Darin for explaining that TryUpdateModel does not support "nested properties".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So the real question is why isn't it binding in the first example?

The answer to your question is very simple: none of UpdateModel, TryUpdateModel or the `[Bind]` attribute support "nested properties" in the include/exclude property list. So do things properly and use view models. Protection against mass property assignment attacks is only one of the millions of reasons why you should be using view models. Well, you seem to have found a *workaround* by performing a second `TryUpdateModel` but if you have many properties on this domain object, your controller action code could quickly turn into spaghetti plumbing code.

Comment: I wasn't saying I didn't want to use view models; I was trying to figure out why the nested properties were not populating. Other examples I saw on the web seemed to insinuate that they should be.

I am also curious about your concern about "spaghetti plumbing code"? What about the code above worries you?

On a related note, do you have any references for the "mass property injection attacks" you mentioned? I tried searching and I keep getting a bunch of unrelated stuff on dependency injection.

Comment: @Sam, sorry, I meant `mass property assignment`. Frameworks such as RoR or ASP.NET MVC which use some sort of model binder to map to objects are vulnerable to this kind of attacks. For example you have a POST action which creates a new User model into the database. So you create a nice form which allows the user to fill his name and password and create button. But unfortunately you don't follow good practices of using view models and you have your POST action take directly your domain User model as argument. Except that this domain model has an `IsAdmin` boolean property...

Comment: ... Of course there is no corresponding field on the form allowing the normal user to set the value of this property but an attacker could forge a request and set IsAdmin=true. The default model binder will simply assign this User domain model and you will save it to the database. The hacker has just created an admini account to your system. So to prevent this kind of attacks you use the exclude/include properties setting...

Comment: ... and you include only the properties you need to be set: Username and Password on the domain model. That's exactly what the second agrument of the TryUpdateModel does. Except that it doesn't work with nested properties as you have already discovered. As far as the plumbing code that I am concerned about, well controller actions should be as slim as possible. They should not contain such binding code. That's not their responsibility. I would recommend you watching the putting your controllers on a diet video from Jimmy Bogard: http://www.viddler.com/explore/mvcconf/videos/1/

Comment: Thanks for the linke to the video. I'll take a look at the video tonight. Doesn't the plumbing code have to go somewhere? If I use a view model, it has to be mapped over to the entity framework object somewhere. I need to add some kind of pluming to the controller to pass the view model to a repository. I need to write a repository to handle all the mapping. Isn't that significantly more work than using one line of code with the include/exclude properties?

Answer (score 1):

I find a number of cases where i want to do the same sort of thing. I also found child objects don't work but lists/collections of child objects do work to be very strange.

I found a good [link](http://goneale.com/2009/07/27/updating-multiple-child-objects-and-or-collections-in-asp-net-mvc-views/) describing how to work around this.

It ends up look something like this :

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Save(int id, FormCollection collection)
{
    User user = null;
    if (id == 0)
    {
        user = new User();
        UpdateModel(user, "User");
        user.Contact = new Contact();
        UpdateModel(user.Contact, "User.Contact");
        user.Contact.Addresses = new EntitySet<Address>();
        UpdateModel(user.Contact.Addresses, "User.Contact.Addresses");
    }
    else
    {
        // get current user object from DB, however you normally do this is fine.
        user = userRepository.GetById(id);
        UpdateModel(user, "User");
        UpdateModel(user.Contact, "User.Contact");
        UpdateModel(user.Contact.Addresses, "User.Contact.Addresses");
    }
    // at this point, model "user" and children would have been updated.
}
...
```